# Putting JavaScript code in a separate file does not work

Tags: javascript, guiders.js

I am working with Optimizely guiders.js example code:

http://jeffpickhardt.com/guiders/

Though if I extract the JavaScript code and place it in a separate file, the guiders do not load.

Here is the edited HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <!-- guider.js requires jQuery as a prerequisite. Be sure to load guider.js AFTER jQuery. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="guider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="guidedTour.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="guider.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="clock" style="border: 2px solid #333; width: 300px; height: 200px; text-align: center;" onclick="guider.next();">
      <br />
      <img src="clock.gif" width=150 height=150 />
    </span>


  </body>
</html>
```

I have all the JavaScript code in `guidedTour.js`, in the same directory.
All `.js` files are also in same directory. And the code worked before extracting it in separate file.

The guiders do not load when JavaScript is in separate file.

I am getting the following error in Chrome:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null
>   jquery-1.5.1.min.js:16"

Trying a more recent version of jQuery throws an error on `guiders.js`.
Anyway it seems a different behavior than if I keep the JavaScript code in the `index.html`.

---

I have created a jsfiddle for the working code:
http://jsfiddle.net/vpMQy/

I do not know how to create a similar jsfiddle with the JavaScript in a separate file so that I can reproduce the problem.

Is it possible to put this JavaScript code in a separate file?

Comment: Hmmm...do your external JavaScript files have: <script> tags? (They shouldn't ifi they do).

Comment: @aquinas I removed the <script> tags. And putting just a javascript alert() worked.

Comment: Did you wrap your JS inside DOM ready handlers properly? Seems like you're trying to get the `clientHeight` from `null`, usually means that the element you're referencing is not in the DOM yet.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté This error comes from the jquery source code (jquery-1.5.1.min.js:16).

Comment: @tucson That doesn't mean that the error is not from your code calling `jQuery` before the DOM is ready. If jQuery wasn't found, it would say something like `$ is not an object`

Comment: The jQuery library on its own won't give you any error, check from which file/line comes that error.

Comment: @Juan Mendes I see. Ok, I'll have a look. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, and if the error points to the jQuery file, you're probably passing an invalid string/reference before calling `.height()`, `.outerHeight()` or something that relates to position.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté It worked: I wrapped the javascript inside $(document).ready(function(){}); and it works.  If you put it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Always wrap your code inside the [DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Or its shorthand

```
$(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Or put your scripts at the very end of the document's `body`:

```
    //...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
 </body>
```

And you won't have problems manipulating them DOM before it's ready. `=]`