# Unobtrusive JavaScript - Separate JS File Not Found

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-javascript

Using the concept [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), I'm trying, for the first time, to place my JavaScript in a separate file from the HTML. But, no matter what I do, I get an error that the file wasn't found.

This is the actual error in the google chrome console (ctrl-shift-j):

```
GET http://localhost:14385/Home/TestPage.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I started with a new MVC 4 app. I created a new test page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="TestPage.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="foo" value="snuh" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I created a new TestPage.js in the same folder:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function dosomething() {
        alert('snuh');
    }

    document.getElementById('foo').onclick = dosomething;
});
```

I've tried the tips posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11951732/279516), but I always get an error that the JavaScript file isn't found. Any idea what's wrong with this simple test?

Note: The TestPage actually displays, with the input box showing.

This is the layout in solution explorer:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a link?

Comment: To the site? No, it's not publicly available. It's just a test app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you reference your javascript from the correct location using server side helpers:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/TestPage.js") %>"></script>
```

This will properly reference the javascript file no matter from which location you have rendered this view. It assumes obviously that you have placed your javascript file in the root of your application. The The convention is to use the Scripts folder for this:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/TestPage.js") %>"></script>
```

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have shown your project structure you seem to have placed the `TestPage.js` file inside the `~/Views` folder. This won't work. This folder is not accessible from the client side. It is explicitly forbidden and not served by IIS. You should never place any static files inside. Move your javascript folder to the `~/Scripts` folder.

Also you seem to be using jQuery inside your `TestPage.js` file but you never referenced it so your script won't work. If you want to use jQuery make sure that you have added it as well:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/TestPage.js") %>"></script>
```

or if you don't want to use jQuery fix your script so that it doesn't depend on it:

```
function dosomething() {
    alert('snuh');
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('foo').onclick = dosomething;
};
```

or if you place your scripts at the end of your DOM you don't even need to wrap them in a document ready handler because at this stage the DOM will be ready and you can manipulate it:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="foo" value="snuh" />
    </div>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/TestPage.js") %>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and then inside your script:

```
function dosomething() {
    alert('snuh');
}
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = dosomething;
```

Comment: I just tried that and got Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:14385/Home/~/TestPage.js.

Comment: You seem to be using the WebForms view engine. I have updated my answer. You should use the `<%= Url.Content() %>` helper.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I actually didn't mean to use the WebForms view engine. I'll make it razor and see if it still works.

Comment: If you use Razor you could directly reference your script like this: `<script src="~/Scripts/TestPage.js"></script>`. The `~/` character is interpreted by Razor WebPages v2 (used in ASP.NET MVC 4) and automatically transformed to the correct location.